# packaging through setup.py do not install the dependent repository

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install a repository (let's say repo1) as pip dependency in other repository (let's say repo2). I added setup.py file in the repo1 which looks like

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
   name='abc',
   version='1.0',
   packages=find_packages(),
   url='https://bitbucket.abc.com/scm/cd/xyz',
   author='ABC',
   author_email='abc@xyz.com',
   description='Module',
   install_requires=[
    'numpy',
    'fiona'
],
dependency_links= 
      ['git+https:/abc.git',
        git+https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git',
        git+https://xyz.git#egg=xyz',
    ],
```

)

when I try to run this script this do not installing the dependent links in the repo1.

Is there any other best way available for this one/ is I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: `dependecny_links` Looks like a typo here.

Comment: @MayankPorwal this was type while formatting in stack overflow, actually in code it's as dependency_links